# Getting image from video and adding to canvas works only if alert is added

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to set an image to a canvas for each video. I'm looping through an array of FileIDs and then trying to get an image from the corresponding video and add it on the canvas.

The following code works if an alert is added just before the `drawImage` function.

The loop:

```
   jQuery.each(arUniqueVideos, function (index, value) {
            SetThumbnail(value);
        });
```

The function:

```
   function SetThumbnail(value) {
            var canvas = jQuery("#img" + value);      
            var video = jQuery("#vid" + value);
            var img = new Image();
            img = video[0];
            var canv = canvas[0];
            //alert('test'); //works only if this alert is added
                canv.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
```

I have tried to draw the image like this but it still doesn't work:

```
  img.onload = function() {
                canv.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            }
```

Comment: I'd guess that the alert is giving the browser enough time to load the video.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, maybe. Any suggested solutions?

Comment: You need to listen to the load events. `oncanplay` will fire when the video can play. Adding the alert just allows the video to load before you try to use it. Without the alert your code runs before the video has loaded.

Comment: @Blindman67 You can answer the question and I will accept it. That was the solution. I have added this:  video.on('canplay', function () {....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the load events. `oncanplay` will fire when the video can play. Adding the alert just allows the video to load before you try to use it. Without the alert your code runs before the video has loaded.

[A list of media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)